# How can I read logarithmic scale?

Tags: functions, logarithms, physics

I've got this histograms:
[image: Spectras of some particles]
How can I read that logarithmic scale? For example, on the histogram 1 there is approximately $10^{-3}$ value at y-axis at 2 value at x-axis. Does it meant that there is a $10^{-3}$ (i.e. 0.001%) chance that there will be such particle at such momentum?

Comment: they don't appear to be normalized, that is, area under the curve (even taking into account log scale) is not 100%. So you can read it in relative terms e.g. "how much more likely to observe energies near 2 GeV, compared to 4 GeV?"

Comment: @PA6OTA My first instinct was also that the plots are normalized such that the "area" under the curve is 1, but it turns out to be much less than 1. Therefore, it must be normalized on some other basis. For example, it may be normalized based on the number of particles fired, and only a small fraction of those particles result in an observable collision.

Comment: The plot is "normalised" like that:
(1.0/Number of Events)/Bin width.

Where number of events $\neq$ number of entries (mainly because those entries are filtered via some criteria). So in this graph the total number of events is 170,000.

Is that normalisation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've asked two questions:

1. How to read a semi-log plot
2. How to interpret a histogram

Your plots are on a semi-log scale, rather than a log-log scale, because the horizontal axis is still linear.

---

To interpret the vertical axis, simply count the minor tick marks.  Labelling an excerpt of the vertical axis explicitly…

```
         ┋
    10⁻³ ┣━━━
9 × 10⁻⁴ ┣━
8 × 10⁻⁴ ┣━
7 × 10⁻⁴ ┣━
6 × 10⁻⁴ ┣━
         ┃
5 × 10⁻⁴ ┣━
         ┃
         ┃
4 × 10⁻⁴ ┣━
         ┃
         ┃
         ┃
3 × 10⁻⁴ ┣━
         ┃
         ┃
         ┃
         ┃
2 × 10⁻⁴ ┣━
         ┃
         ┃
         ┃
         ┃
         ┃
         ┃
         ┃
    10⁻⁴ ┣━━━
         ┋
```

---

Histograms normally have integral counts on the vertical axis, but this one has small fractions instead.  I assume that the vertical axis has been normalized such that the total number of samples is 1.  Therefore, the vertical axis should be interpreted as relative probability density rather than a count.

Histograms are normally bar graphs rather than line plots.  Imagine that each `+` symbol represents a vertical rectangle with its top at the `+` mark and its sides being halfway between it and its neighbours.

It looks like the `+` symbols are spaced horizontally such that there are 10 data points per major tick, i.e. at intervals of $0.2 \frac{\mathrm{GeV}}{c}$.  Therefore, each data point represents data samples at the marked momentum, $\pm\ 0.1 \frac{\mathrm{GeV}}{c}$.

Taking your example, reading the first histogram at $x = 2$, I would interpret a `+` symbol at $x = 2.0 \frac{\mathrm{GeV}}{c}$, $y = 6 \times 10^{-4}$ as

> $6 \times 10^{-4}$ probability of a collision when the momentum is in the range $2.0 \pm 0.1 \frac{\mathrm{GeV}}{c}$.